# Merge/Dissolve Polygon overlapping within

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, merge, dissolve, combine

I have a polygon that has been broken down to an intersecting analysis point. Each segment has its own acreage within an acre field on the attribute table. I want the intersecting lines to be removed and the polygon to be one whole with the acreage of each small segment all summed up together. I have tried dissolving by the acre field, and unchecking multi-part lines but the lines and small segments remain.

[image]

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS?

Comment: Yes, not an advanced license though.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the [Dissolve tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/dissolve.htm) incorrectly. Read the [Help](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/dissolve.htm): The dissolve field is the criteria by which you want to combine your features. If you want to combine all your features and sum the acres, leave the dissolve field blank and use Acres as the Statistics field.